# JPA one2many relation, how to keep the ids

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entity classes: User, Product and Fridge. The Fridge is something between User and Product. I mean that in the Fridge I store the ID of the Product, the id of the User and some quantity. And I need to see the IDs that are(stored) used for relation.

**User Entity Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
@JsonManagedReference(value = "user-fridge")
private List<Fridge> fridge;
}
```

**Product Entity Class :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "measurementUnit")
private Enum measurementUnit;

@Column(name = "calories")
private int calories;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
@JsonManagedReference(value = "ingredients-products")
private List<Ingredients> ingredients;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
@JsonManagedReference(value = "fridge-product")
private List<Fridge> fridge;
}
```

**Fridge Entity Class :**

```
@Entity(name = "Fridge")
@Table(name = "fridge")
public class Fridge{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
@JsonBackReference(value = "user-fridge")
private User user;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="product_id")
@JsonBackReference(value = "fridge-product")
private Product product;

@Column(name = "quantity")
private int quantity;

@Transient
private DateFormat dform = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
@Transient
private Date intermediar = new Date();

@Column(name = "added_at")
private String added_at = dform.format(intermediar);
}
```

What I get is something like this :

```
"fridge": [
        {
            "id": "79baae3e-8189-4ebb-8a40-2116a77693b8",
            "quantity": 25,
            "added_at": "25/08/21"
        }
```

But I need the id's of the product and user as well.
How should I structure my model to get that?

Comment: Long time since I been to java, but are the 1:M values the right way 'round?  It looks like one user has many fridges and one product has many fridges?

Comment: Yes, it's like 1 user can have many entries in fridge table, and one product can be in different fridges. when i add something to fridge will be like   {
            "id": "79baae3e-8189-4ebb-8a40-2116a77693b8",
            "quantity": 25,
            "added_at": "25/08/21", user_id: "something", product_id: "something"
        }